# ajax file upload: differentiate different forms inside uploadProgress callback

Tags: jquery

I am following this [example](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html) on JQuery form plugin official website. It works except that I have four forms on the page, each form has one file input field and a progress `.bar`. I only want to update `.bar` width of the form whose file is being uploaded. How can I differentiate each `.bar` inside `uploadProgress` callback?

```
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        $('.bar').width(percentVal)
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with IDs or some attributes and use a generator function when you define your upload callbacks, like so:

```
 function getProgressUpdater(target) {
    target = $(target); 
    return function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
      target.width(percentVal);
    }
 }

 // ajax bla ...
 {
   uploadProgress : getProgressUpdater('.bar[data-progress-bar="some-id-or-name"'),
 // other ajax stuff
 }
```

Edit:/
This solution can be easily extended to a more sophisticated scenario. Imagine 4 forms. Now put an additional attribute in each form like so:

```
<form class="upload" data-form-id="my-form1"> <!-- stuff --></form>
<form class="upload" data-form-id="my-form2"> <!-- stuff --></form>
<form class="upload" data-form-id="my-form3"> <!-- stuff --></form>
<form class="upload" data-form-id="my-form4"> <!-- stuff --></form>
```

And each form has a progress bar which looks like this:

```
<div class="progressbar" data-progress-of="my-form1"></div>
```

Now you're able to attach the jquery form like this:

```
$('.upload').each(function(i, form) {
   var $form = $(form), formId = $form.attr('data-form-id'), $progbar = $('.progressbar[data-progress-of="' + formId + '"]');

   $form.ajaxForm({
    // bla
     uploadProgress : getProgressUpdater($progbar)
   });
});
```

This way you have to add only about 10 lines of code but make it very flexible and robust.

Comment: Four forms use the same `uploadProgress` for `ajaxSubmit`. So whatever you put in `some-id-or-name` will still be the SAME for all four forms. I don't understand how it solves my problem

Comment: That's the point: you need to rewrite it so that it uses different functions. To prevent you from writing the same code 4 times use this generator function.

Comment: Don't get it. Maybe you can add some code to show how to do it exactly

Comment: Now I got you. So each form get its own version of `ajaxSubmit`. It will certainly work but looks very heavy. I don't have to do this in `success` or `error` which have `$form` passed in as argument.

Comment: Yeah, right but that doesn't help you in the updateProgress because there it's missing. Another approach would be to rewrite the plugin so that your uploadProgress gets it passed in too. 

By the way, it may look heavy but it really isn't. Concentrate on performance when you really must. Most of the time the JS event model will handle it so good that you don't have to think about it. This is also a case where you don't have to think about it.